# Parse CSV in bash and assign variables

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, csv, awk

I have a csv of the format (Working on Bash on linux)

```
DN , MAC , Partition ,  

123 , abc , xyz  
321 , asd , asd
```

I am able to parse it using awk by using

```
eval MAC=($(awk -F "," '{print $1}' random.csv))
```

This is done for each column in the CSV and therefore I can call `DN[2]`, `MAC[2]` etc individually which is manual and parses them individually.

But how can I parse the csv by row?
For example : If I call for `DN` is `123`, the corresponding `MAC` and `Partition` should also be returned.

Comment: Do you only want the first row that matches, or should all rows be returned?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try a loop:

```
while IFS=, read dn mac partition
do 
  echo "Do something with $dn   $mac and $partition"
done < file
```

---

To select a record you could use a case statement:

```
P2=123
while IFS=, read dn mac partition
do 
  case $dn in
    ($P2) echo echo "Do something with $dn   $mac and $partition" ;;
    (*)   echo "Do nothing" ;;
  esac
done < file
```

Comment: using this I would be able to read the variables individually.
I would be able to return them individually but I would want them to read by row. For example if I call row 2 using a variable P2 (say)It should be able to return MAC(2), DN(2) etc

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` :

```
read -p "Gimme the DN integer >>> " i
awk -v i=$i -F' , ' '
    NR>1{
        dn[NR]=$1
        mac[NR]=$2
        partition[NR]=$3
    }
    END{
        for (a=2; a<=NR; a++)
            if (i == dn[a])
                print dn[a], mac[a], partition[a]
    }
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

file1 stores all the DN for which you want to retrieve the information

```
#parse.awk

BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS= "\t"}

FNR==NR{ a[$1]; next }

$1 in a { print $1,$2,$3}
```

call `awk -f parse.awk file1 csvfile.csv`